# angular directive ng-show not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have very stright forward angular code,ng-show directive in the below code not working

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
     "<div id="temperature" ng-show='false'> &#x2103;</div>"




<div id="temperature" ng-show='false'>{{temperature}} &#x2103;</div>
```

Here ng-show is not doing any job

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: If you want to hide it all the time, use `class='ng-hide'` instead of `ng-show=false`

Comment: ng-show takes an expression not a literal

Comment: Here is fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/eLwrvb7g/

Comment: The `ng-show` seems to be working in your example, only one div is showing as expected.  Note that `$scope.temperature1` in your example is never used in case this is related to what you're finding in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

it got solved,there was some problem with Angular src itself,changing it to CDN solved my problem